# Convert an ordinary LINQ query to lambda expression

Tags: linq

```
from _tupleRows in this.TupleSet
from _member in _tupleRows.Members
where (_member.HasChildMembers && !_member.DrilledDown)
select new
{
  _member1 = _member,
  _member2 = (from _searched in this.TupleSet
              from _compareMember in _searched.Members
              where (_member.UniqueName == _compareMember.UniqueName && 
                     _member.LevelDepth == _compareMember.LevelDepth && 
                     _compareMember.DrilledDown)
              select _compareMember).FirstOrDefault()
};
```

I need to convert this simple LINQ expression to an equivalent lambda expression

Comment: Please take the trouble to format your code for better readability. It is indented much too much - why do we need to scroll? There, fixed that for you.

Comment: Download LinqPad, it'll "convert" it for you.

Comment: Resharper can do this for you in a couple of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from _tupleRows in this.TupleSet
from _member in _tupleRows.Members
where (_member.HasChildMembers && !_member.DrilledDown)
select new
{
    _member1 = _member,
    _member2 = (from _searched in this.TupleSet
                from _compareMember in _searched.Members
                where (_member.UniqueName == _compareMember.UniqueName
                    && _member.LevelDepth == _compareMember.LevelDepth
                    && _compareMember.DrilledDown)
                select _compareMember).FirstOrDefault()
};
```

becomes:

```
this.TupleSet
    .SelectMany(tupleRows =>
        tupleRows.Members
            .Where(member => member.HasChildMembers && !member.DrilledDown)
            .Select(member => new
            {
                _member1 = member,
                _member2 = this.TupleSet
                    .SelectMany(searched =>
                        searched.Members
                            .Where(compareMember =>
                                member.UniqueName == compareMember.UniqueName
                             && member.LevelDepth == compareMember.LevelDepth
                             && compareMember.DrilledDown))
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

They're really not hard to convert.  Just start at the top and append as you go.

Something like:

```
this.TupleSet.SelectMany(ts => ts.Members)
    .Where(m => m.HasChildMembers && !m.DrilledDown)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        _member1 = m,
        _member2 = this.TupleSet.SelectMany(ts => ts.Members)
            .Where(other => m.UniqueName == other.UniqueName 
                && m.LevelDepth == other.LevelDepth
                && other.DrilledDown
                )
            .FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

No guarantees this is perfect or will even compile, but then I'm not trying to do your work for you, I'm trying to give you a demonstration of how you might do these conversions yourself.

Also, do yourself a favor and use simpler identifiers in lambdas when you can.  They're very limited scope, and you're chaining calls to make one big statement, so often it will usually be very obvious in context what a variable means.  I may not have the best example here, but the original variable names were way too verbose, IMO.

The nested query also seems a little strange.  If there is a way to structure your data so you don't have to do that nested query I think you'll get better perf and simpler queries.